# Homeomorphism between $[0,\infty)^n$ with Upper Half-Space $\mathbb{H}^n$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

I've been working through an exercise in Lee's Smooth Manifold. The author ask us to show that the space $\bar{\mathbb{R}}_+^n := [0,\infty)^n$ is homeomorphic to upper half-space $\mathbb{H}^n := \mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times[0,\infty)$, both equiped with the usual topology.

I managed to construct a homeomorphism $f : \bar{\mathbb{R}}_+^2 \to \mathbb{H}^2$ defined by restriction of the map $f(z) = z \, e^{i\theta} = r \, e^{i2\theta}$ to $\bar{\mathbb{R}}_+^2=[0,\infty) \times [0,\infty) \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \approx \mathbb{C}$. Alternatively, a more pleasing  the map like $f(z) = z^2$. So we have
$$
\mathbb{H}^2\approx \bar{\mathbb{R}}^2_+. 
$$
To proceed i tried for $n=3$ case but it's messy. After a while i came up with this induction: Suppose that $\mathbb{H}^n\approx \bar{\mathbb{R}}^n_+$ for all dimension less than or equal to $n$. Clearly this hold for $n=1$. By definition of upper half-space,
\begin{align}
\bar{\mathbb{R}}^{n+1}_+ = \bar{\mathbb{R}}^{n}_+ \times \bar{\mathbb{R}}_+ &\approx \mathbb{H}^n \times \bar{\mathbb{R}}_+ = \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times \bar{\mathbb{R}}_+ \times \bar{\mathbb{R}}_+  \\ &\approx \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times \mathbb{H}^2 = \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R} \times  \bar{\mathbb{R}}_+ = \mathbb{R}^n \times \bar{\mathbb{R}}_+ = \mathbb{H}^{n+1}.
\end{align}
In the argument above i use the following result : if $A \approx B$ then $A \times C \approx B \times C$, which i think can be done by set $f : A \times C \to B \times C$ to be $f(a,c) = (\varphi(a),c)$, where $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism between $A$ and $B$.

> Is this proof correct ? Is there any other (correct) proof for this ? I tried to googling it but i found nothing. If possible, can anyone give me references for manifold with corner ? Thank you.

Comment: Your argument is correct. I cannot think of a better proof.

Comment: I agree with @KaviRamaMurthy.  I tried for a bit this morning to work out an explicit homeomorphism in higher dimensions, but it was complicated, and I think your argument is best.  For completeness, my idea was to map the "corner" to the origin, and then hyperplanes at distance $r$ from this corner to hemispheres of radius $r$ in the half-space. You can think of this in three dimensions as "flattening out" the corner space, the way you would a crumpled piece of paper.

Comment: I like your proof, it's perfectly fine, and I don't even think of it as messy. The homeomorphism $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^n_+ \to \mathbb{H}^n$ that you get is simply a composition of $n-1$ functions, each of which applies the case $n=2$ to a pair of coordinates.

Comment: @LeeMosher Ok sir. Thank you very much.